# My app keeps crashing when I initiate the NFC Function

Tags: android, mobile, nfc

I'm working on an app that will take in inputs from a tag and insert the values into specific variables(still working on it). However, when I put a pre-set NFC tag near my phone, supposedly the app will get the information from the tag. Instead it initiates the app and then crashes right after.

`public class NFCAdding extends Activity {

```
private static final String TAG = "MealPlan";
private EditText foodName, protValue, carbValue, fatValue, energyValue;
private Button addBreak, addLunch, addDinner;
NfcAdapter mNfcAdapter;

private boolean mResumed = false;

PendingIntent mNfcPendingIntent;
IntentFilter[] mNdefExchangeFilters;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.nfc_add);

    foodName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.nfc_food_name);
    protValue = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.nfc_prot_value);
    carbValue = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.nfc_carb_value);
    fatValue = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.nfc_fat_value);
    energyValue = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.nfc_energy_value);
    addBreak = (Button)findViewById(R.id.nfc_add_breakfast);
    addLunch = (Button)findViewById(R.id.nfc_add_lunch);
    addDinner = (Button)findViewById(R.id.nfc_add_dinner);

    mNfcPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
            new Intent(this, getClass()).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP), 0);

    // Intent filters for reading a note from a tag or exchanging over p2p.
    IntentFilter ndefDetected = new IntentFilter(NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED);
    try {
        ndefDetected.addDataType("text/plain");
    } catch (MalformedMimeTypeException e) { }
    mNdefExchangeFilters = new IntentFilter[] { ndefDetected };

    addBreak.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){
         public void onClick(View v) {
             Intent intent = new Intent();
     intent.setClass(getApplicationContext(), AddItem.class);
     startActivity(intent);
     finish();                                               
     }
```

});

```
    addLunch.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){
     public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setClass(getApplicationContext(), LunchAdd.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();                                               
    }
```

});

```
    addDinner.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){
     public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setClass(getApplicationContext(), DinnerAdd.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();                                               
    }
```

});

```
}

 @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mResumed = true;
        // Sticky notes received from Android
        if (NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED.equals(getIntent().getAction())) {
            NdefMessage[] messages = getNdefMessages(getIntent());
            byte[] payload = messages[0].getRecords()[0].getPayload();
            setNoteBody(new String(payload));
            setIntent(new Intent()); // Consume this intent.
        }
        enableNdefExchangeMode();
    }

 private void setNoteBody(String body) {
        Editable text = foodName.getText();
        text.clear();
        text.append(body);
    }

 private void enableNdefExchangeMode() {
        mNfcAdapter.enableForegroundDispatch(this, mNfcPendingIntent, mNdefExchangeFilters, null);
    }

    private void disableNdefExchangeMode() {
        mNfcAdapter.disableForegroundDispatch(this);
    }

NdefMessage[] getNdefMessages(Intent intent) {
    // Parse the intent
    NdefMessage[] msgs = null;
    String action = intent.getAction();
    if (NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED.equals(action)
            || NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED.equals(action)) {
        Parcelable[] rawMsgs = intent.getParcelableArrayExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_NDEF_MESSAGES);
        if (rawMsgs != null) {
            msgs = new NdefMessage[rawMsgs.length];
            for (int i = 0; i < rawMsgs.length; i++) {
                msgs[i] = (NdefMessage) rawMsgs[i];
            }
        } else {
            // Unknown tag type
            byte[] empty = new byte[] {};
            NdefRecord record = new NdefRecord(NdefRecord.TNF_UNKNOWN, empty, empty, empty);
            NdefMessage msg = new NdefMessage(new NdefRecord[] {
                record
            });
            msgs = new NdefMessage[] {
                msg
            };
        }
    } else {
        Log.d(TAG, "Unknown intent.");
        finish();
    }
    return msgs;
}
```

}`

Comment: please share the logcat logs..

Comment: `java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{org.project.MealPlan/org.project.MealPlan.NFCAdding}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView cannot be cast to android.widget.EditText` Like this? I'm sorry I'm new here..

Comment: Seems like one of your EditText properties is defined as TextView in the layout xml.

Comment: please share your xml.. you are trying to cast text view to edit text..

Comment: Sorry for that.. I changed the TextView to EditText in the xml.` java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {org.project.MealPlan/org.project.MealPlan.NFCAdding}: java.lang.NullPointerException` now I get this error. Is it because I dint add the onResume part?

Answer (score 0):

AS per your logs one of the following is not the EditText but it is a TextView:

```
foodName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.nfc_food_name);
protValue = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.nfc_prot_value);
carbValue = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.nfc_carb_value);
fatValue = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.nfc_fat_value);
energyValue = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.nfc_energy_value);
```

check for element with ids `nfc_food_name, nfc_prot_value, nfc_carb_value, nfc_fat_value and nfc_energy_value`. It looks like one or more of them are TextView not the EditText..